# Output a C++ string including all escape characters

Tags: c++, cout

I have a string like this:

```
string s = "\t Hello \n";
```

When I print it then it gives me a tab then Hello then a new line. However, is there anyway I can print it such that I see this in my console:

```
\t Hello \n
```

In other words, I want the string to disregard the escape characters and treat it as an actual string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using \ in a string as literal instead of an escape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103445/using-in-a-string-as-literal-instead-of-an-escape)

Answer (score 4):

> In other words, I want the string to disregard the escape characters and treat it as an actual string?

If the string is hard coded, as you show, you can modify it to use:

```
string s = "\\t Hello \\n";
```

If you want to be able to handle any string thrown at your program, you'll have to write a function and deal with all the escape sequences allowed by the language.

```
std::ostream& writeString(std::ostream& out, std::string const& s)
{
   for ( auto ch : s )
   {
      switch (ch)
      {
         case '\'':
            out << "\\'";
            break;

         case '\"':
            out << "\\\"";
            break;

         case '\?':
            out << "\\?";
            break;

         case '\\':
            out << "\\\\";
            break;

         case '\a':
            out << "\\a";
            break;

         case '\b':
            out << "\\b";
            break;

         case '\f':
            out << "\\f";
            break;

         case '\n':
            out << "\\n";
            break;

         case '\r':
            out << "\\r";
            break;

         case '\t':
            out << "\\t";
            break;

         case '\v':
            out << "\\v";
            break;

         default:
            out << ch;
      }
   }

   return out;
}
```

Use it as:

```
writeString(std::cout, s);
```

Comment: This won't handle non-printable characters properly.

Comment: @Timmmm - which ones and how? You can always extend the example.

Comment: E.g. the for the null character you'd probably want to print `\x00` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to escape the backslash so it would look something like this

```
string s = "\\t Hello \\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Put **doublebackslash** because `\\` doublebackslash produce a `\` single backslash.

```
string s = "\\t Hello \\n";
```