# C++ Escape occurrences of \ in a string

Tags: c++, string, c++11

Is there a simple way to escape all occurrences of `\` in a string? I start with the following string:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string escapeSlashes(std::string str) {
    // I have no idea what to do here
    return str;
}

int main () {
    std::string str = "a\b\c\d";

    std::cout << escapeSlashes(str) << "\n";
    // Desired output:
    // a\\b\\c\\d

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I am looking for the inverse to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5612182/4920424) question. The problem is that I cannot search for `\` in the string, because C++ already treats it as an escape sequence.

**NOTE:** <s>I am not able to change the string str in the first place. It is parsed from a LaTeX file. Thus, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12103512/4920424) answers to a similar question does not apply.</s> **Edit:** The parsing failed due to an unrelated problem, the question here is about string literals.

**Edit:** There are nice solutions to find and replace known escape sequences, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2417770/4920424) answer. Another option is to use `boost::regex("\p{cntrl}")`. However, I haven't found one that works for unknown (erroneous) escape sequences.

Comment: How about you show a sample of the file and your parsing code?

Comment: Add another \ before every slash and try

Comment: To search for special characters put a `\ ` in front of them, eg `\\ `. You don't need to modify the *source* data.

Comment: BTW you don't need to "escape" the source data either. It's just fine as it is. If you try to inspect the characters in the debugger you'll see that the `\ ` character is displayed as `\\ `. Escaping is needed only for string literals in the source code. If you used `cout << str` you'd see the original string without modifications

Comment: I would prefer not to touch the parsing code. A related question would be: Is there a way to search for *any* escape character in a string?

Comment: What do you mean by *"It is parsed from a LaTeX file"*?  Have you got a script that extracts strings from your LaTeX sources and produces C++ source as output?  (In which case, fix the script.)  Or is your C++ code reading LaTeX as input? (In which case, you'll already have literal `\ ` characters in your string, and your example code is not representative of what you're doing.)

Comment: I found the problem with the parser and it was not related to this question. When trying to understand the problem by using string literals instead of the parsed string, I only made it worse. I will remove the note as it is misleading.

Answer (score 8):

You can use raw string literal. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str = R"(a\b\c\d)";

    std::cout << str << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a\b\c\d
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to convert the string literal `a\b\c\d` to `a\\b\\c\\d`, i.e. escaping the backslashes.

Why? Because the compiler converts `\c` and `\d` directly to `c` and `d`, respectively, giving you a warning about `Unknown escape sequence \c` and `Unknown escape sequence \d` (`\b` is fine as it is a valid escape sequence). This happens directly to the string literal before you have any chance to work with it.

To see this, you can compile to assembler

```
gcc -S main.cpp
```

and you will find the following line somewhere in your assembler code:

```
.string "a\bcd"
```

Thus, your problem is either in your parsing function or you use string literals for experimenting and you should use raw strings `R"(a\b\c\d)"` instead.