# QT - C++ Adding char ' " ' to QString

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I need to compose a string like:

```
<page myIndex = "1">
```

where 1 is the value of a variable stored in memory.

My fist try:

```
QString str = "<page pageIndex = " + myVar + ">";
```

But it does not contain the ' " ' around the myVar value.
I've tried with ' only, like this:

```
QString str = "<page pageIndex = " + '"' + myVar + '"' + ">";
```

but it gives compile error.

Comment: Try using `"\""`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using \ in a string as literal instead of an escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103445/using-in-a-string-as-literal-instead-of-an-escape)

Comment: I would do it like: `QString str = QString("<page pageIndex = \"%1\">").arg(myVar);`. This will work even if `myVar` is an integer.

Comment: @vahancho it ends out like this: "<page pageIndex = \"1\">" which is not good

Comment: @Elena, you are wrong - it results `<page pageIndex = "1">` which is what OP wants.

Comment: @vahancho but I am printing it and it ends out like I said, which is not the result I asked for...

Comment: @Elena, how do you print it?

Comment: qDebug() << QString("<page pageIndex = \"%1\">").arg(myVar);

Comment: @Elena, that's because `qDebug` inserts quotation marks around strings and escapes existing ones. You may use the following statement to print it out without quotes: `qDebug().noquote() << QString("<page pageIndex = \"%1\">").arg(myVar);`.

Comment: @vahancho it's ok now! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are already several answers for your problem but I'd like to add one more to the list:

```
auto str = QString("<page pageIndex = \"%1\">").arg(myVar);
```

Seems to be a bit more elegant from my point of view and gets the job done.